# How to open input fields based on radio button selection in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have two radio buttons. Based on which radio button is selected, I need to open input fields to collect some data. How can I achieve this using react?

I tried manipulating the onClick and onChange functions.

Comment: Please share code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {

const [itWorks, setItWorks] = useState(false)

function handleClick(){ SetItWorks(!itworks) }

return (
<div>
{itWorks ? 
  <>
    'It works!' 
    <input type="text" />
  </>: 'It does not'}

<button onClick={() => setItWorks(!itWorks)} >Press me
  <input type='radio' aria-selected onClick={handleClick} />

 </div>
) }

export default App;
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had to change the initial state according to my use case. Thank you!

Comment: You can thank by adding upvote or flag the answer.